# Is it possible to pass API from some url to openapi-generator in gradle?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I have some `consumed.yaml` API and now for generating classes with `openapi-generator gradle plugin` - i need to store this `consumed.yaml` file in my spring boot project. Short example of gradle task i use:

```
task clientApiGenerate(type: GenerateTask) {
    generatorName = "jaxrs-cxf-client"
    inputSpec = "path/to/consumed.yaml"
    ...
}
```

So the question - can i use URL for downloading API file, for example, from gitlab and then use it in this line: 
`inputSpec = "path/to/consumed.yaml"`

The following versions are currently in use, but can be changed, if necessary:

- gradle: 6.8.3
- openapi-generator gradle plugin: 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's possible, as in this [example](https://pythonrepo.com/repo/OpenAPITools-openapi-generator#2---getting-started) bellow. Didn't tried it for myself. However it's simpler to have spec along implementation, but that depends on situation :)